# Return non null field in Many To Many intermediary class/model Django

Tags: python, django

I think this is a python question (maybe `for x in list`), but might have a django framework ¿query/or-the-like?

I have an intermediary class/model:

```
class VehicleFeatures(models.Model):
    personal_equipment = models.OneToOneField(PersonalEquipment, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_equipment = models.OneToOneField(CommercialEquipment, null=True, blank=True, )
    personal_vehicle = models.OneToOneField(PersonalVehicle, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_truck = models.OneToOneField(CommercialTruck, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_tractor = models.OneToOneField(CommercialTractor, null=True, blank=True, )
    …

    def __unicode__(self):
        # assume one and only one is allowed
        return '{}'.format(self.whichever_of_the_fields_exists)
        # Extra Credit :)
        # assume any number is allowed
```

**How do I return the Model.field that has a reference** (ultimately to get that model's name, to pass back to the other side of this many-to-many)?

Notes:

- trying to follow option 2 and 3 [in this article](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/)
- I am not worried about performance (yet) but if you are aware of a low cost option, then please teach us why one is better than another
- Visual of models

  - 121-Referent: Vehicle (abstract model) with concrete models [listed above]
  - M2M: VehicleFeatures (to connect to concrete models)
  - 12M: Features (fields for many vehicle features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that is sometimes used in similar "entity-attribute-value" models is to add an additional field which `OneToOneField` is populated. Something like this:

```
class VehicleFeatures(models.Model):
    personal_equipment = models.OneToOneField(PersonalEquipment, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_equipment = models.OneToOneField(CommercialEquipment, null=True, blank=True, )
    personal_vehicle = models.OneToOneField(PersonalVehicle, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_truck = models.OneToOneField(CommercialTruck, null=True, blank=True, )
    commercial_tractor = models.OneToOneField(CommercialTractor, null=True, blank=True, )

    # Add a field to store the type of relation that is set for this instance
    relation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When the object is saved, you do the `for x in list` thing and determine which field is not null, and set `relation_type` to the name of that field, e.g.:

```
def save(self):
    for k in ['personal_equipment', 'commercial_equipment', 'personal_vehicle' ...]:
        if getattr(self, k) is not None:
            self.relation_type = k
    return super(VehicleFeatures, self).save()
```

This is significantly more efficient than doing the same loop every time you query the object.

Then your `__unicode__` method would be:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{}'.format(getattr(self, self.relation_type))
```

This is for the case when only one field is ever set, but you could extend it quite easily to support multiple fields - e.g., by making `relation_type` a comma-separated string, or if your database supports it, an `ArrayField`.